# SQL Server 2014. Fastest way to update a numeric field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can think of this 2 options, but not sure if there is any other one. What will be faster?

```
DECLARE @dateVar datetime = '20170101';

UPDATE SALESLINE 
SET REMAINSALESFINANCIAL= 0 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, CREATEDDATETIME) < CONVERT(DATE, @dateVar)
```

or

```
DECLARE @dateVar datetime = '20170101';

UPDATE SALESLINE 
SET REMAINSALESFINANCIAL= 0 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, CREATEDDATETIME) < CONVERT(DATE, @dateVar)
AND REMAINSALESFINANCIAL != 0
```

- REMAINSALESFINANCIAL is numeric
- I have an index on CREATEDDATETIME

Comment: What is the data type of `CREATEDATETIME`? That is an important detail to answer your question.

Comment: CREATEDATETIME is datetime data type

Comment: Is there an index that contains both columns? What do you know about the distribution of values?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that REMAINSALESFINANCIAL does not contain any `NULL`s you can just use

```
UPDATE SALESLINE
SET    REMAINSALESFINANCIAL = 0
WHERE  CREATEDDATETIME < CONVERT(DATE, @dateVar)
       AND REMAINSALESFINANCIAL <> 0
```

As `CONVERT(DATE, @dateVar)` will have a time part of `00:00:00` and so any datetime that is *less than* this must have a date part of the previous day or earlier.

Casting a `datetime` column to `date` doesn't prevent index use but it is [more optimal not to](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea/34052#34052).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answers that the second option should be faster but there are additional considerations from a performance perspective.

If the assigned value has a time of midnight, the explicit conversion is unnecessary.

Instead of a local variable, I suggest the query be parameterized so that stats histogram is used instead of average cardinality to better optimize the query. This is automatic if your actual query uses a stored procedure parameter directly or is called as a parameterized query from application code. If parameter sniffing is an issue (unlikely here, IMHO), add an `OPTION RECOMPILE` query hint.

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'
UPDATE SALESLINE 
SET REMAINSALESFINANCIAL= 0 
WHERE
        CREATEDDATETIME < @dateVar
    AND REMAINSALESFINANCIAL <> 0;'
        , N'@dateVar datetime'
        , @dateVar = '20180101';
```

Answer (score 1):

The second version is better.  If you have some rows where `REMAINSALESFINANCIAL = 0`, then the engine will not even try to update those rows, filtering them out earlier in the process.  Note:  this assumes that `REMAINSALESFINANCIAL` is never `NULL`.

In general, having a function on a column in the `WHERE` is a bad idea.  In this case, though, SQL Server will still use an index, so that is not a problem.

It would be interesting to compare the performance with an index on `(CREATEDDATETIME)` versus `(CREATEDDATETIME, REMAINSALESFINANCIAL)`.  In the first case, it has to work harder to find the rows to update.  In the second, it has to update the index when it changes the values.

Comment: I was just expecting SQL Server to be intelligent enough to do that filter automatically.. Hence the question